# ProcessReply('result','0') message after running GWT project

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am new to Google Web Toolkit technology. I downloaded plug-in for eclipse and created first project. After i run project in eclipse i get URL that i should copy in browser, but when i do that i get "processReply('result','0')" message on a blank html page. Please help.

Comment: are you working on which browser? are you installed plugin for gwt development in browser?

Comment: Google Chrome, but i tried explorer also, yes i downloaded plug in.

Comment: Do not use google chrome for development, use firefox. Those strange ids are coming from google chrome in dev mode. In production it will be ok.

Comment: I tried firefox but still same msg appears.

Comment: I think this issue not be with gwt. This might be help to solve issue. Refer link: http://linux.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/linuxadmin-l/processreplyresult0-4707473

Comment: In run configuration i changed port number from 8888 to 8887 and now it is working in every browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the default port 8888 to 8889 resolved this for me. Debug config > Arguments > program args

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding " -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 " to your project Arguments through Run Configuration.

Comment: The default port number, on which eclipse run web projects, is 8888. For some reason that port number is always occupied. I set up, in run config, to automatically select unused port number and that solved problem. Anyway thanks.